Send action option is not available in final approval section in approval process
I have created an Send Action. Like below:

When I try to add this in Final Approval Actions for approval process, I am not able to see the Send Action available in the dropdown:

Only Field Update action is available.
How can we make Send Action available in this dropdown?
